# Intellij turn off delete file confirmation?

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, delete-file

This is about the popup when deleting a file from the Project Tool window (right-click file, click `Delete...`)
[image: delete popup]

Various searches on this returned null and it's both annoying and an extra click/keystroke many times a week. Maybe some buried setting or macro magic will solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the options under:

> File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Confirmation

There are option for "When files are created" and "When files are deleted"

Comment: I see you are relatively new to SO - Welcome!!! I've already got that set for version control. I clarified my question about which delete confirmation I am asking about.